# How to use "LIKE" clause in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have just started reading about datastax cassandra few days back so I am sort of newbie in this technology. I have some doubts/queries and need to get clarification. Such as:

1. **Which version of Cassandra is more suitable to use 2.1/2.0 ?** Right now I am using 2.1 which is not stable and recommended to use. Even though using this(2.1) leads to some problems in future then what would be the better choice to opt for ?
2. **Does Cassandra supports "Like" clause ?** If yes, in which version ? **And how** ? If not, then what can be the alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any query for Cassandra as same as SQL:LIKE Condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition)

Comment: This is a good question, but a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition

Comment: Have you looked into DSE? You can achieve this via DSE Search.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm using apache cassandra 2.1.2. It's been running in prod since release. No major issues.
2. No... look to pair it up with Lucene or elasticsearch. If you're on DSE, DSE search nodes can give you this feature. You might even want to check out http://www.openstratio.org/blog/advanced-search-in-cassandra/ . The guys at stratio have added the ability to have a text column representing a lucene query, which is quite interesting.