# LIKE operator in Cassandra CQL

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I'm new to Cassandra and I need to do a text search through one or more VARCHAR type fileds using CQL and PHP. Usually with MySQL I used the LIKE operator but as I know in Cassandra is not possible, which is the alternative for do that in CQL? 
Note that I'm using Cassandra version 2.2.1 and the DataStax PHP-Driver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any query for Cassandra as same as SQL:LIKE Condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition)

Comment: It looks like duplicate but it is not - that question is about "Cassandra 0.8.x" and current is about "Cassandra 2.2.1" so author hope that LIKE s appear, I suppose.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this question in search during the post creation but as I seen later it is referred to an old version of Cassandra and I didn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no LIKE operator in cassandra. It's "by design". You must use [elasticsearch (Solr, Lucene)  or similar solutions](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) beside cassandra to develop search abilities.

Comment: Sorry for delay, so no way to do this in pure CQL?

Comment: No Way, And no plans for this. If you need search (LIKE) you need to go with some 3rd party indexers.

Comment: I do not know the reason you choice cassandra (I prefer cassandra as well)   but you can review other NoSQL solutions if you just start a project - for example mongodb have search ability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like

Comment: I chose Cassandra for speed and scalability, also on big amount of records, but sometimes happens that a text search is needed, so I'll try with Lucene plugin because actually I didn't find any solution in pure CQL, thanks a lot for the answer, in these days I'll install and try Lucene, but if a field is already a primary key, I can't use Lucene's index on it? Anyway I though that Cassandra had search capabilities, it was developed by Facebook for mail so is strange that there is no search in it.

Comment: I've tried the cassandra-lucene-index
, I done an index with this syntax: `CREATE CUSTOM INDEX team_index ON team (name) USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index' WITH OPTIONS = {'refresh_seconds' : '1','schema' : '{fields:{name : {type : "string"}}}'};` but I get this error: `ServerError: <ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.IndexQueryHandler.process(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/cassandra/service/QueryState;Lorg/apache/cassandra/cql3/QueryOptions;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/apache/cassandra/transport/messages/ResultMessage;">`

Comment: @RyanJ you can ask for help or any issue or problem you have in the github issues page of stratio-lucene-index [stratio Lucene Index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, now I'm waiting for Datastax PHP driver to be released in order to upgrade to Cassandra 3 so then I'll be able to retry some tests with Lucene hoping for a better result, if there will be other problems I will report all to Lucene support or mailing list.