# How to use like operator in cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra database cassandra:2.2.3 in my application and i should use like operator to get all the names starts with 'A%'.

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX  empnames_idx ON d.emp (ename)
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

After creating the index when i run the below query :

```
select * from d.emp where ename like 'A%';

<Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:49 no viable alternative at input 'LIKE' (...* from d.emp where ename like .....)"
```

Comment: Cassandra doesn't support the keyword LIKE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition

Comment: SASI Index is not ready for production use yet.

Comment: What version of cassandra are you using? there is no such thing as 6.0.2.

Comment: There is a LIKE keyword now thats a very old answer @Yamini

Comment: @ChrisLohfink - Changed it to 2.2.3 version.

Comment: Basically i need all the empnames starts with A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported until 3.4+ but should upgrade to 3.11.latest. You may want to configure your index as well, an excellent walkthrough is here: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058

Comment: Thanks for the link.