# Is there a way to delete records in AWS Managed Cassandra Service table using any operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I'm getting syntax error when using like operator to delete all the records in my table

[image: n]

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query is wrong. You have to define the partition key / clustering key in a cassandra delete query.

https://www.guru99.com/cassandra-query-language-cql-insert-update-delete-read-data.html

To delete all records in a table:

```
truncate mytable;
```

Comment: Just deleted a single record using the same query without like operator and it executed successfully. My partition key is name in this scenario. 

delete from "testkeyspace".Hiringsheet where name='Eujish Selvaraj';

My concern is that I'm not able to execute the same query with like operator

Comment: there is no like operator in cassandra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition

Comment: truncate is supported in cassandra but aws managed cassandra service does not support truncate operator.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mcs/latest/devguide/cassandra-apis.html

Comment: okay, how can I delete all the records in my table other than using truncate. any idea?