# "LIKE" and "ILIKE" queries in AWS Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, sql-like, cql, amazon-keyspaces

As there is no support for custom index in AWS Keyspaces what would be the best solution / pattern to be able to run LIKE or ILIKE queries on specific columns of a Cassandra Table?

In vanilla Cassandra, you can use SSTable secondary index to use LIKE queries, but we can't in AWS...

[Is there any query for Cassandra as same as SQL:LIKE Condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905795/is-there-any-query-for-cassandra-as-same-as-sqllike-condition)

Feeding an OpenSearch service, or even a good old Postgres at the same time of updating Keyspaces seems a bit overkill to me.

Fetching all columns in-memory somewhere to do the query seems slow as well.

What would be the lightest infra / architecture to implement to provide a LIKE query support based on AWS Keyspaces as source of truth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lexi-graphical Select statement to narrow your query down the same way you would do a LIKE statement. If you needed to further narrow it down you could do that narrowing client side. I would love to learn more your use case so I can better assist you.