# spring data Cassandra LIKE query on secondary indexed cluster column

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cqlsh, spring-data-cassandra

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "20" 2023-03-21
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 20+37)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+37, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Springboot Version: `3.0.1`
Cassandra Version:

```
cqlsh:hipi> SHOW version;
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.7 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]
```

Table description

```
cqlsh:abc> DESCRIBE TABLE books;

CREATE TABLE abc.books (
    author_id text,
    name text,
    created_at timestamp,
    status boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (author_id, name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name ASC)
    AND additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = false
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';

CREATE INDEX books_name_idx ON abc.books (name);
```

While querying with WHEN =

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE name='8b481c6e-48a0-4552-a624-9e8fbad4f930';
```

Result

```
cqlsh:hipi> SELECT * FROM books WHERE name ='8b481c6e-48a0-4552-a624-9e8fbad4f930';
 author_id                            | name                                 | created_at                      | status
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------
 a1c08312-d8fe-46f8-b625-bf43da2a2920 | 8b481c6e-48a0-4552-a624-9e8fbad4f930 | 2023-06-13 09:36:07.311000+0000 |   True
```

But while using with LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE name LIKE '%8b4%';
```

Result

*InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="LIKE restriction is only supported on properly indexed columns. name LIKE '%8b4%' is not valid."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `LIKE` filtering in CQL, you need to build your index as a SSTable Attached Secondary Index (SASI).  SASI indexes are considered to be "experimental," so they are disabled by default.  To enable them, flip this setting in the `cassandra.yaml` for all nodes, and restart the cluster:

```
sasi_indexes_enabled: true
```

Next, create your index like this:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX books_name_idx ON abc.books (name)
    USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

Then, this should work:

```
> SELECT * FROM books WHERE name LIKE 'Mastering%';

 author_id | name                           | created_at                      | status
-----------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------
      6866 | Mastering Apache Cassandra 3.x | 2023-06-13 12:51:12.802000+0000 |   True

(1 rows)
```

Comment: There are annotation like `@SASI.NonTokenizingAnalyzed` and `@SASI.StandardAnalyzed` I tried both but it does not work, the above table structure is with `@SASI.NonTokenizingAnalyzed` but not working, will check how to use Cassandra.yaml file in springboot.

Comment: With docker, I could not change the Cassandra.yaml file I changed and copied inside container multiple times with `docker cp /opt/homebrew/var/services/git/hipi-cassandra-be-service/cassandra.yaml cassandra:\etc\cassandra\cassandra.yaml` it does not work, but without docker, I could change it and get it work. path of the file in macOS is /opt/homebrew/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml. Thank you so much.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu excellent!  Glad you got it figured out.